# How to get zoomed xAxis labels from eCharts?

Tags: javascript, echarts

After using dataZoom, I need to get x-axis label values from the chart. For [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-stack&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWtJgDYFMBcya6GOAHmAQOQDKYAhgMYDWOAJrAIIBOOdsAwgAs6XMJSIBfADREwwYFkggCqYhi4QA5ppxcqdUhADOlGWoPGACsAjQwulUTVgAniHyxKDLsCMmzarBYdABGOFiOgcQhjEyaPgCu0Kz8CsB6ngDEAGIAIrkAHADMAKymToEMaRmUXJoxABQAnFKwAIxtrQBMXa0ADAB0TQAsAJTlURIVU-jSRLg6yZHErHT0BADalACiALZ0EFimngCq0FBwHKz-ngBqEKw4wJzXx5S5EDwMYq00vFwMQSwbbQTS2HCUAC6kgCcgUIWApGW6AAZrwwAkeMjiEY6AA3HAcIwASX2OhUM2IlLm6FW9AAWvJdpsKqpAq53FQjFgHroJoEjPRRAQun0AmocEtYAU-tMApCAqQOIYjCy1GznG4PF41jhNOkXPy1AikqsuC4AOJ0ZSwFF0LBGHDilZrOibSgAWRgbwAKgkIb8AOpsX2CBJvbIaN7UNbRpJQ6ZEBVEFzK4xq4ga4gc7V4-3-o3EaB0XbagAyoXC_gq6GLpbLwAYawuVF2D1YuELtZLOCtNuGYprsDrOB9ZDAtBcuGxahRMDA2RLhxcVAARNRgJiGDhYDHoEZYJYfKvWrj9wBaR0aFFd4hzuzUCAALw8bV6Q_QVSw6SoISwBedWZANgCwjArMIIkIKJ0CMQRgAAdwIMAuH9YDUXnRc2ywFdPHXTcAR3PcDyPYAT1gM8jEvXQIBvNDbXnR8XwIN9gMpWYkwCeIHmxBEwDkZlPDaPoAFJ-RpcjqJwVVYA2VkhxHKg9gOI5gJzKgeWgAMhxwXYQGEIx0yg6C5wYBJpMoK8ICk8RJmAuk3Rkt8xXaIpenaPpOhc4ZWiaZyuiKPyhOhNRxPQLNu1LKgPi-H4hzUzwNK0qIdL0ugDOk8K70bMyuUkkwh1Cl11hk1znKKVzWgCzzyu82Ail8yqAsq0VgqpZ1MoUzxqH-QFgVBcFb3iyhEtvYIIJnHE4MQ9RUI_WAQF8CBIBgKg5BAGzAkK9AUv0wzMvQ0zzMs6yCrs11NhlHznKE5ymiKWq3walympclrE3QaEJAAbhQFBdhcIQRDAAYYAaSh7KfJljgaEARBLIxRgQAA-Iyqn3BQcAGb9NBhuHdgRn6JFGIA), here I need to get the names of days that are inside the zoom slider.

```
myChart.on('datazoom', (params) => {console.log(params);})
```

Is only giving me coordinates of start and end the zoom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get these values from the event params but you can still get them from the chart options:

```js
myChart.on('datazoom', (params) => {
  var option = myChart.getOption();
  console.log(option.xAxis[0].data.slice(option.dataZoom[0].startValue, option.dataZoom[0].endValue + 1))
})
```